# Determine cache read/write/hit/miss by memory access trace file

Tags: c, caching, trace

my homework is to determine the # of cache reads/writes/misses/hits given a trace file through a sample program.

Say, for example this is the first 10 lines of an example trace output.

```
0x37c852: W 0xbfd4b18c
0x37cfe0: W 0xbfd4b188
0x37cfe3: W 0xbfd4b184
0x37xfe4: W 0xbfd4b180
0x37cfe5: W 0xbfd4b17c
0x37cfe9: W 0xbfd4b128
0x395bcb: R 0xbfd4b128
0x395bce: R 0xbfd4b128
0x37cff4: W 0xbfd4b158
0x37cff9: W 0x39deac
```

How can I determine what I need to know by analyzing each line?

Thanks, and if you have any educational sources please let me know.

Comment: Well, for a start, you need to know the parameters of the cache (total size, line size, associativity, write policy, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can determine the cache parameters from the trace file. But you need to have either of the following things:

1. Format of the trace file. (which I doubt you have access to)
2. Know the parameters of the system i.e. cache size, addressing bits (explaining)

Actually cache is based on temporal locality and spatial locality. So for you to determine

- **Spatial Locality:** Check if the address fetched is the address fetched recently + word size (can be double word size etc.) example: you recently fetched 0x4000 and next access is 0x4008. If the line/block length (i.e. length of data fetched by cache in one go). To be precise you also need to know whether cache is set associative and how much, which will help in replacement and also replacement policy to be precise (which i highly doubt someone will ask for homework)
- **Temporal Locality:** Check if the address accessed is called again in near future and if it has not been replaced (because some other address with same index and different tag was requested)

I hope this will try to clear out on how to approach. For having good understanding, I will suggest Computer Organization and Design book chapter Memory Hierarchy.